# Function returning two outputs

Tags: function, f#

I would like to create a function that produces two outputs.
Please consider the following example:

I built two functions that, given a list of integers, return a list of elements in even position and elements in odd position.

```
let rec alternate1 lst =
    match lst with
    [] -> []
    | [x] -> []
    | x::y::xs -> y::(alternate1 xs)

let rec alternate2 lst =
    match lst with
    [] -> []
    | [x] -> [x]
    | x::y::xs -> x::(alternate2 xs)
```

And here everything is fine. Now, the problem: I would like to create a *single* function `alternate` that returns both lists with signature `alternate: int list-> (int list * int list)`.

```
let rec alternate lst =
    match lst with 
    [] -> []
    | [x] -> []
    | [x::y] -> [y]
    (*My attempts:*)
    | x::y::xs -> ((y::alternate xs),  (x::alternate xs))
    | x::y::xs -> [(y::alternate xs);  (x::alternate xs)]
    | x::y::xs -> ((y::alternate xs) && (x::alternate xs))
```

So far, no solution worked. I am pretty sure the problem is even silly, but my [reference](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/match-expression/) did not help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Why not return a tuple of both lists?

Comment: That would be ideal, but I still fail to put it in practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're calling `alternate` recursively, the recursive call will *also* return you two outputs, so of course you can't treat that tuple as a list - as in `y::alternate xs`.

You have to first take the tuple apart, process the parts separately, and recombine them into a tuple before returning:

```
let nextXs, nextYs = alternate xs
x::nextXs,  y::nextYs
```

And then, your base cases should also return two outputs - otherwise your function has unclear return type:

```
| [] -> [], []
| [x] -> [x], []
| [x; y] -> [x], [y]
```

(also note that your match case `[x::y]` actually matches a list of lists, which contains exactly one list, in which the first element will be named `x`, and the tail of the list will be named `y`. In order to match a list of exactly two elements, use `[x; y]` or `x::y::[]`)

Combining it together:

```
let rec alternate lst =
    match lst with 
    | [] -> [], []
    | [x] -> [x], []
    | [x; y] -> [x], [y]
    | x::y::rest ->
        let nextXs, nextYs = alternate rest
        x::nextXs,  y::nextYs
```

Also: technically, the `[x; y]` base case is not needed, because it would be covered by the last case just fine.

Comment: Thank you Fyodor, now I surely have a better perspective on the procedure.

Answer (score 3):

[Fyodor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637204/4925216) is complete (as usual)
So I just wanted to add a tail-recursive version of his code (along with some reduction) to those who wanted to know how to make it tail-recursive (using [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style))

```
let alternate xs =
  let aux cont even odd (evens, odds) = cont (even :: evens, odd :: odds)

  let rec loop cont = function
  | [] | [_]    as xs -> cont (xs, [])
  | even :: odd :: xs -> loop (aux cont even odd) xs

  loop id xs
```

Alternatively one can use 2 continuation for each *side* list, but here I think it's not so useful as both *sides* are manipulated each time, but anyway

```
let alternate xs =
  let aux cont x xs = cont (x :: xs)

  let rec loop evenCont oddCont = function
  | [] | [_]    as xs -> evenCont xs, oddCont []
  | even :: odd :: xs -> loop (aux evenCont even) (aux oddCont odd) xs

  loop id id xs
```

Comment: Sehnsucht, thank you for your answer. It is another useful piece of knowledge :)